# How to move multiple meshs in different directions with three.js?

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, mesh

I have a problem. With the for loop I have created 100 meshes. They all have the position of 0,0,0. But I want that these 100  meshes move separated in all different directions.

This is my code to create the 100 meshes

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x2194ce} );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);

mesh.position.x = 0;
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.position.z = 0;    
scene.add(mesh);    
}
```

This is the code how I though to move the 100 meshes, but It move only one mesh

```
function render(){
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
            mesh.position.x +=0.1;
            renderer.render(scene, camera); 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only the last mesh in your `mesh`
 variable. In order to move all, you can store them in an array, then iterate the array in your render loop and assign the New Position. 
`mesh.position.z = 0; meshes.push( mesh );`

And in render:

```
 for( var i=0; i<meshes.length; i++){
      meshes[i].position.x += 0.1;
 }
```

I've not tested this.